# Intent-filter abnormal behavior with samsung file browser

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I'm creating an intent filter for a specific extension (.infi) for my app. It works correctly with ES file explorer & Solid explorer. However when I open the file with Samsung default file explorer (Device Galaxy Tab S2) it shows a strange message "No application to perform this action", on other device (Note 4) it tries to open the file with Adobe Reader with an error message. Here is my code from manifests file :

```
<activity android:name=".ImportCollections">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="file" />
            <data android:host="*" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.infi" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:host="*" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.infi" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="content" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.infi" />
            <data android:host="gmail-ls" />
        </intent-filter>


    </activity>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding **<category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE"/>**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future references, I looked for another open source app implementing this feature correctly. These guys are doing a great job:

https://github.com/ankidroid/Anki-Android/blob/develop/AnkiDroid/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

Here is my code that worked (just replace "infi" with your custom extention)

```
<activity
        android:name=".ImportCollections"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:parentActivityName=".ManageCollections">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="*"
                android:mimeType="*/*"
                android:pathPattern=".*\\.infi"
                android:scheme="http" />
            <data
                android:host="*"
                android:mimeType="*/*"
                android:pathPattern=".*\\.infi"
                android:scheme="https" />
            <data
                android:host="*"
                android:mimeType="*/*"
                android:pathPattern=".*\\.infi"
                android:scheme="content" />
            <data
                android:host="*"
                android:mimeType="*/*"
                android:pathPattern=".*\\.infi"
                android:scheme="file" />
        </intent-filter>
        <!-- MIME type matcher for .infi files coming from providers like gmail which hide the file extension -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="application/infi" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/x-infi" />
            <data
                android:mimeType="application/octet-stream"
                android:scheme="content" />
            <data
                android:mimeType="application/zip"
                android:scheme="content" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Hi, did you make Samsung My Files open your app? Do you know where is the catch? My app open from browsers and other file managers, but not from Samsung My Files.

Comment: The repo is gone, could you please elaborate on how you fixed this?

Comment: See my comment over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50407193/open-custom-filetype-in-samsung-file-explorer#comment95806841_52624829

This does not work on a Samsung S8 running Android 8 unfortunately.